# marker dragend event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, maps, marker

I have this code:
the code in function() of 'dragend' event doesn't execute and the latFld and llgFld in the document doesn't update
any help ?

```
    var map;
    var marker;

    function initMap()
    {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.780577, -64.279906);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    if (marker) {marker.setMap(null)}

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: map,
        draggable:true
    });

    // display the lat/lng in your form's lat/lng fields
    document.getElementById("latFld").value = event.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById("lngFld").value = event.latLng.lng();
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(){
    alert(marker.getPosition());
    document.getElementById("latFld").value = marker.getPosition().lat();
    document.getElementById("lngFld").value = marker.getPosition().lng();
    });
    }
```

Comment: It may seem obvious, but, do "latFld" and "lngFld" exist with that exact name or do you get undefined when getting? are you using a js logger?

Comment: body onload="initMap()">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <input type="text" id="latFld">
    <input type="text" id="lngFld">
</body>

Comment: I suppose for the question that click event executes, have you put event.latLng in an alert to see what you get?

Comment: Yes, I put anything to see if the code execute, also I put alert('dragend !') and nothing happend

Comment: can you check if event "dragstart" is called? try this.getPosition() instead

Comment: I try google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function(){
    alert('dragstart');
    });

Comment: nothing happend, there is a problem with the google.maps.event.addListener

Comment: this is the body html tag
<body onload="initMap()">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <input type="text" id="latFld">
    <input type="text" id="lngFld">
</body>

Comment: may be the problem is with the way of the function load call

Comment: try this after initMap function: google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

Comment: I make it, id any of you wants the code just ask for it, My map does as follow: create map, create a single marker and drag it to a new position or move with a click to a new position and a infowindow shows a position and more data